# Trying To Populate Array w/ List of Categories from a Custom Taxonomy

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, categories

I am trying to populate an array with a list of categories in a custom taxonomy I created.

The taxonomy's slug is "clipcat". I only want the array to populate with children of a clip with the same slug as the page slug the list is on.

Here's my code so far:

```
           <?php 
                global $post;
                $slug = get_post( $post )->post_name;
                echo $slug;
                $taxes = array('clipcat');
                $args = array(
                    'parent' => $slug,
                ); 
                $categories = get_terms( $taxes, $args );
            ?>
            <p>
                <?php print_r($categories); ?>
            </p>
```

You can see what this code outputs here: http://noellesnotes.com/portfolio/seventeen/

To my knowledge, the code is as it should be, but when I print the array (the last line in the code), the array is empty even though I know the clip category that is successfully assigned to $slug has three sub categories (so I must be coding something wrong).

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the `get_terms` documentation, the `parent` key requires an integer:

"Parent 
(integer) Get direct children of this term (only terms whose explicit parent is this value). If 0 is passed, only top-level terms are returned. Default is an empty string"

I believe you are passing a string

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks for that answer. That is why it's not working. Back to the drawing board. Thank you!